# How to display a textbox onclick of a radiobutton which is checked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `HTML` as follows :

```
<div class="col-lg-2 camt hidden">
    <label for="camt">CEAV Amount:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 camt hidden radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="..xyz.." name="camt" id="camt1" required onclick="functions()" />XYZ</label>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="ABC" name="camt" id="camt2" required onclick="functions()" />ABC</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="number" class="form-control hidden popup1" onchange="functions()" id="textpart" placeholder="Enter value. Only numbers." required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="NA" name="camt" required id="camt3" onclick="functions()" />NA</label>
    <hr/>
</div>
```

I have a function `editData()` in `javascript` which sets the value of all my inputs on the screen. It also checks the `radio button` when the `form` is loaded. So, if the radio button `camt2` is checked I want to display a `textbox` in front of it. But it is not working. The two functions `editData()` in which I want to check if the `radio button` is checked or not, and `funcitons()` which sets the `textbox` to be hidden or visible. both of them are below : 
**editData()**

```
function editData() {
    var logfromform = document.getElementById('logref').value;
    var key;
    for (key in Log1) {
        if (Log1[key].LogReference == logfromform) {

            if (Log1[key].RedemptionPrice == '100%') {
                document.getElementById('redprice1').checked = true;
                functions();
            } else if (Log1[key].RedemptionPrice == 'NA') {
                document.getElementById('redprice3').checked = true;
                functions();
            } else {
                document.getElementById('redprice2').checked = true;
                functions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**functions()**

```
function functions() {
    if (document.getElementById('camt2').checked) {
        $("#textpart").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $("#textpart").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

When I run the **HTML** `form`, the `JavaScript` is being entered, but the `removeclass` doesn't work on the `textbox`
Any help much appreciated!
Please note that I am running **Internet Explorer 11.0.9600** and `NO` I don't have an alternative browser to carry forward my work on.

Comment: create jsfiddle with your code for better understanding

Comment: $("input[type='radio']").is(":checked") should return a boolean maybe?

Comment: Used bootstrap class `hidden` for the same @Arvind

Comment: Tried creating a`jsfiddle` for the same @venkat7668 , but I cant because the `hidden` property from `bootstrap` isn't working on it anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

JQuery:

```
function functions(){       
    if($("#camt2").is(":checked")){
        $("#textpart").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $("#textpart").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried what you said, didn't work for me. My console also shows no errors. @DSlee

Comment: Try changing cam2 to camt2... worst typo haha

Comment: I cant seem to find the same, could you please gimme the exact place where the typo is @DSlee

Comment: In the line if($("#camt2").is(":checked"))

Make sure it is #camt2 not #cam2

Comment: Try adding console.log($("#camt2").is(":checked")) before the line we were just referring to... to try and work out the problem

Comment: The console says `true` but the `textbox` is still not coming up :/ @D Slee

Comment: Try adding console.log($("#textpart").attr("class")) after. removeClass to see if the hidden class has been removed

Comment: It gives that the class hidden is removed from it.@D Slee

Comment: Try logging $("#textpart").css("display")

Comment: @D Slee, I did console.log($("#textpart").attr("class")) and I got where I was making mistake. And now things are working fine. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I think your parent div is hidden. So you also need to make **col-lg-4** div also visible. Try this :

```
function functions(){       
if(document.getElementById('camt2').checked)
    {
        $(".col-lg-4").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#textpart").removeClass("hidden");
    }
    else{
    $("#textpart").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried what you said, didn't work for me. My console also shows no errors. @AkshatG

Answer (score 1):

hi i want to suggest that if you already uses the jquery then why we need to making class and manipulating that..?

you can use **.show()** and **.hide()** for that you should try.

```js
function functions(){       
    if($("#cam2").is(":checked")){
        $("#textpart").show();
    } else {
        $("#textpart").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't work for me. The `removeclass` and `addClass` that I have are working perfectly fine with other `classes` and `divisions` But I guess my code isn't working because I am setting the radio button to `checked` through the `JavaScript` function and then the `textbox` gets displayed depending on the `checked` or `unchecked` status of the `radio button`

Comment: @ one thing that why you need to check every time using function you can just write action using the **'change'** event also then you need not to call function every time it will called when any radio button's value will be changed

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what youre saying will work when I have to change the values myself. but that isn't the case. Mine is dynamic. My `JavaScript` is setting the `radio button` to be `checked` which in turn calls the function `functions` @HimeshAadeshara

Answer (score 0):

I copy your html and js codes and it is working for me. Well I had to remove the hidden class on `div.col-lg-4.radio` to show the elements. But the function `functions` is working well for me. Is displaying any js error on your console?

Comment: Tried what you said, didn't work for me. My console also shows no errors. @oeddy